# JQuery - Remember Toggle State with Cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I have the following JQuery to toggle the header on my page. How can I use JQuery Cookie to remember the toggle state?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnToggleHeader').click(function() {
    $('#Header').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good resource regarding javascript and cookies is http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp.

Based on this website we are given 3 functions: setCookie, getCookie and checkCookie (which gives us a demo of how to use the other two.)

To set the initial state of a toggle, something like this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// The initial load event will try and pull the cookie to see if the toggle is "open"
var openToggle = getCookie("open") || false;
if ( openToggle )
    $("#Header").show();
else
    $("#Header").hide();

// The click handler will decide whether the toggle should "show"/"hide" and set the cookie.
$('#btnToggleHeader').click(function() {
    var closed = $("#Header").is(":hidden");
    if ( closed )
       $("#Header").show();
    else
        $("#Header").hide();
    setCookie("open", !closed, 365 );
});

});
```

Note: this is just a reference, I did not have time to test. Hope it helped.

Comment: Awww, boo! The logic is there, please post your final code- keep it clean, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSearchToggle").click(function () {
        var closed = $("#Header").is(":hidden");
        if (closed)
            $("#Header").show();
        else
            $("#Header").hide();

        setCookie("open", closed, 365);
    });

    var openToggle = getCookie("open");    
    if (openToggle=="true") {        
        $("#Header").show();
    }
    else {        
        $("#Header").hide();
    }

});

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```